# preloader поверх php

Tags: javascript, php

Загружаю на странице тяжёлый php код, страница грузит в районе 2 секунд.
Написал прелоадер на чистом js, css - по итогу он не отображается до тех пор, пока php код не загрузится.
Какие варианты, чтобы прелоадер отображался сразу после открытия страницы (ещё до загрузки php), а исчезал после полной загрузки (включая php)?
Желательно максимально простой способ, лишь для того, чтобы понял, как это работает.

Мой код:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Прелоадер для сайта (демо)</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }

    .preloader {
      /*фиксированное позиционирование*/
      position: fixed;
      /* координаты положения */
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      /* фоновый цвет элемента */
      background: #e0e0e0;
      /* размещаем блок над всеми элементами на странице (это значение должно быть больше, чем у любого другого позиционированного элемента на странице) */
      z-index: 1001;
    }

    .preloader__row {
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      width: 70px;
      height: 70px;
      margin-top: -35px;
      margin-left: -35px;
      text-align: center;
      animation: preloader-rotate 2s infinite linear;
    }

    .preloader__item {
      position: absolute;
      display: inline-block;
      top: 0;
      background-color: #337ab7;
      border-radius: 100%;
      width: 35px;
      height: 35px;
      animation: preloader-bounce 2s infinite ease-in-out;
    }

    .preloader__item:last-child {
      top: auto;
      bottom: 0;
      animation-delay: -1s;
    }

    @keyframes preloader-rotate {
      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }

    @keyframes preloader-bounce {

      0%,
      100% {
        transform: scale(0);
      }

      50% {
        transform: scale(1);
      }
    }

    .loaded_hiding .preloader {
      transition: 0.3s opacity;
      opacity: 0;
    }

    .loaded .preloader {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Прелоадер -->
  <div class="preloader">
    <div class="preloader__row">
      <div class="preloader__item"></div>
      <div class="preloader__item"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php
  // PHP код, который грузится несколько секунд
  ?>



  <script>
    window.onload = function () {
      document.body.classList.add('loaded_hiding');
      window.setTimeout(function () {
        document.body.classList.add('loaded');
        document.body.classList.remove('loaded_hiding');
      }, 500);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А нужно было всего лишь воспользоваться ajax и подгрузить жирный кусок асинхронно.

Comment: В любом случае ведь придется отслеживать окончание загрузки.

Comment: Придётся. Но у вас сначала загрузится страница. Потом покажется прелоадер, а потом и жирный контент

Comment: Никогда, к сожалению, с аяксом не работал. Что конкретно нужно в данном случае? Вынести жирный кусок в отдельный файл?

Comment: Нужно, чтобы жирный кусок грузился отдельно (по другому URL). Ну а потом либо сюда https://habr.com/ru/post/14246/ либо сюда http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax-запрос

Comment: Вариант оптимизировать "тяжёлый" код не приходил в голову?

Comment: Не приходит, к сожалению.